# How to achieve this CSS effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

I was wondering how the guys who made [carv.ai](https://carv.ai) achieved the text masking effect on the paragraph "Carv connects wirelessly ...".

I know that we can mask a background image on a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that you can do to have text masking, is either give the masking div a greater `z-index` than the text, or make the text the same color as the masking color. Then you can use jQuery to make the div slide away.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#id").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
```